# Passing value from one parameter to another

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am creating a report in SSRS. Queries are working fine. I am getting the results if I hard coded the input values.

Now I have added three parameters:

1. YearMonths
2. SUGName
3. collection

---

1. YearMonths - Data is coming from the SQL query directly. No issues in that.
2. SUGName -

   ```
   select cia.AssignmentID,CIA.Collectionid, concat(grp.Title,' -- ', CIA.CollectionName) as deploymentName from
       v_CIAssignment cia
             inner join v_CIAssignmentToGroup  atg on cia.AssignmentType=5 and atg.AssignmentID=cia.AssignmentID
             inner join v_AuthListInfo grp on cia.AssignmentType=5 and grp.CI_ID=atg.AssignedUpdateGroup
    where concat(datepart(yyyy, grp.DateCreated), '-', RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(grp.DateCreated)), 2)) = @YearMonths
     Order By grp.Title desc
   ```

   This is also working.
3. collection -

   ```
   select cia.AssignmentID,CIA.Collectionid, concat(grp.Title,' -- ', CIA.CollectionName) as deploymentName from
       v_CIAssignment cia
             inner join v_CIAssignmentToGroup  atg on cia.AssignmentType=5 and atg.AssignmentID=cia.AssignmentID
             inner join v_AuthListInfo grp on cia.AssignmentType=5 and grp.CI_ID=atg.AssignedUpdateGroup
     where cia.AssignmentID = @SUGName
     Order By grp.Title desc
   ```

   It is not working and is giving an error. The query is working fine. I checked that by putting in SUGName manually.

   Below is the error I am getting.

   > System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
   >   The Value expression for the query parameter ‘@SUGName’ refers to a non-existing report parameter ‘SUGname’. Letters in the names of parameters must use the correct case.

Comment: the error message implies that you have not declare the `@SUGName` parameter in the ssrs parameters, or in your dataset ( parameter mapping tab or something like that).  Or maybe you have a typo in `@SUGName`, in your query or the parameter definition.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters references in SSRS are case sensitive. When you are referring to the parameter in your query, make sure **SUGName** is in the same case in your main query.